# Error ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL"

Tags: sql, oracle

Cree una tabla de médico

```
CREATE TABLE MEDICO(
   DNI NUMBER(10),
   NOMBRE VARCHAR2(100) PRIMARY KEY,
   FECHA_NACIMIENTO DATE,
   COD_PAIS_RESIDENCIA REFERENCES PAIS,
);
```

Y una de país

```
CREATE TABLE PAIS(
   CODIGO NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
   NOMBRE VARCHAR2(100),
   POBLACION NUMBER(10)
);
```

Queriendo eliminar un médico que resida en un país con menos de 10 millones de habitantes, intenté implementar este código

```
DELETE FROM MEDICO
WHERE (SELECT P.POBLACION
FROM MEDICO M, PAIS P 
WHERE P.CODIGO = M.COD_PAIS_RESIDENCIA) < 10;
```

Pero me aparece este error
"ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721"

Comment: Debe eliminar a todos.

Comment: Hola me puedes decir si la respuesta te fue útil, y en caso de ser correcta marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te indicaron, el error es que tu subconsulta no puede devolver mas de una fila, si la vas a comparar con un numero, porque sql espera comparar ese numero con un numero, no con un conjunto de filas...

Para evitar el join (que en un delete, suena medio raro) lo que tenes que hacer es devolver el conjunto de claves que vos queres, y eso ponerlo en el where.

O sea que eliminemos de la tabla medicos

```
delete from medicos
```

los que esten en paises que cumplan con la condicion

```
select codigo from pais where poblacion < 10
```

y para agregar esto ultimo, lo hacemos en un where pegandolo al campo COD_PAIS_RESIDENCIA, quedando la consulta completa asi:

```
delete from medicos
where COD_PAIS_RESIDENCIA IN (
    select codigo from pais where poblacion < 10)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió este fragmento y sí eliminó mis médicos.